# Merge uploaded Amazon S3 images into CloudFront

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I started to integrate CloudFront into my exciting Rails App, everything with CloudFront is working fine, except that the old uploaded images can't be accessed.

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',                        
    :aws_access_key_id      => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],     
    :aws_secret_access_key  => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'], 
  }
  config.asset_host     = ENV['CLOUDFRONT_ENDPOINT']
  config.fog_directory  = 'oktob-editor'                     
  config.fog_public     = true                                        
  config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control'=>"max-age=#{365.day.to_i}"}
end
```

Example of old uploaded image

```
https://oktob-editor.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/post/image/127/thumb_Ruby_on_Rails.svg.png
```

After I integrated CloudFront and set `asset_host` it becomes

```
http://ID.cloudfront.net/uploads/post/image/127/thumb_Ruby_on_Rails.svg.png
```

with

```
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>D368D2E641BBBB64</RequestId><HostId></HostId></Error>
```

So is there a way that enable old images to work properly with CloudFront

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like changing the Restrict Bucket Access to Yes makes it to work

[image]

Comment: Presumably you also allowed Cloudfront to update the bucket policy?   This is fine as long as you understand that *everything* in the bucket is now public.

Comment: Thanks @Michael-sqlbot, but how this will affect the security of the bucket, how to prevent this, should I restrict this to one IP for example, what is the best way to do this

Comment: I should have been more explicit, when I said public: publicly readable.  If you have private content in the bucket, the action you may have needed was a bucket policy allowing certain path prefixes for be publicly readable, or to change the attributes on the individual objects to make them public.  You can't restrict/allow on IP, since CloudFront has thousands of them... But you could alternately modify the cloudfront config so only certain path patterns would proxy to the bucket.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks for the great explanation, actually the content in the bucket are just images of posts that anyone can show them in the front-end